# How to open varying number of images in folder using for loop in batch file

Tags: windows, batch-file, for-loop

I have `c:\Images` folder and in it different amount of images to work with every day. I need to make a batch file which would open all of those in Windows photo viewer.
A for loop like this `(int i=0; i<numberOfItemsInFolder; i++)` should open WPV numberOfItemsInFolder times.
I found this line that starts WPV

```
%SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen %1
```

and ofc, this line that opens the folder `%SystemRoot%\explorer.exe "C:\Image"`

Answer (score 0):

Just loop over the folder:

```
for %%F in (c:\Images\*.*) do %SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen "%%~fF"
```

(I don't know how this command handles quotes, maybe you have to remove them from `"%%~fF"`)

If not all images should open instantly, try this:

```
@echo off
for %%F in (c:\Images\*.*) do (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\rundll32.exe "%ProgramFiles%\Windows Photo Viewer\PhotoViewer.dll", ImageView_Fullscreen "%%~fF"
    echo/any key for next image...&pause>nul
)
```

*~Tim*

Comment: Thanx for reply, but nothing happens

Comment: you open the batch and nothing happens? Add a `pause` in front of the Photo-Viewer Execution and let it write the output in a file: `...>log.txt 2>&1` You can also try to open the image with the default image-viewer: `start "" "%%~fF"`

Comment: still nothing, doesn't even open WPV, just opens command prompt and closes it

Comment: This is strange. I understand that the PhotoViewer-call is not working, because the filename has to be unquoted (`%%~fF` instead of `"%%~fF"`) but at least the for-loop should work... does `c:\Images` exist and contain files?

Comment: what is the output of the following code (in a batchfile)? `@for %%F in (C:\Images\*) do @echo %%F`